# Why is Chrome crashing in a b1s instance in Azure but works fine on AWS t2.micro instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-chrome, crash

I just launched a B1s instance on Microsoft azure and I installed google chrome on the instance. But it crashing frequently due to RAM. Previously I am using AWS's t2.micro instance which configuration is almost same as Azure's B1s instance. On AWS it's running fine.

So can anyone tell why this happening?

Answer (score 0):

While searching on google I found that it occur due to the less virtual memory allocated in default in azure instance, So I simply increase the virtual memory in azure from 500 MB to 3000 MB and now its working fine.

You can change virtual memory by following steps

1. Open This PC
2. There in anywhere in blank space right click and select property
3. Go to Advance System Setting
4. click on setting of performance
5. Then go to Advanced Tab and click change
6. If Automatically is checked then uncheck it, then select custom size and Enter Initial Size and Maximum Size and click set after that it might ask to restart. (You can enter both value same, Recommended value is 3500 MB)